# Create session in java using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, session, servlets

I want to create a session using a client side jQuery API in Java.

Is it possible to create such a session in jQuery in Java EE, i.e. via JSP and Servlet?

Answer (score 1):

You can create cookie in [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)(can do in pure JavaScript as well). you can read the cookie using the server side. then you can create the session in the server side.

Comment: jQuery cookie plugin is very useful. I have used but also a problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765172/cookie-read-and-write-issue-jquery-to-jsp

Answer (score 0):

Any request you make to a  JSP/Servlet from the client (with/without jquery) will result in a session (if one doesn't exists already).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you don't just want to create the session, you want to store some values in it as well. If this is the case, your best bet is to make an AJAX call to a Servlet that will take the values from the request and put them in the session. jQuery can manipulate cookies, but can't manipulate session data directly.