# Cookie read and write issue- jQuery to JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, cookies

using [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) I create cookie:

```
$.cookie('uom', '1-23-235(K)');
```

When I read it from JSP, it Return me only the following

```
1-23-235
```

and if I remove parentheses while creating cookies, such as

```
$.cookie('uom', '1-23-235 K');
```

then there is no problem! All working is fine.

How can I overcome this because user can enter any symbol like parentheses

Comment: It works fine with the brackets in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hfe8U/

Comment: you are right, when I read data from server side, then there is a problem. @dda suggested solution is helpful. but it print like this 1-23-235%28K%29

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping (aka URL-encoding) the strings you set as cookies:

On the JS side:

```
escape(cookie);
```

On the Java side:

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(cookie, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: According to your suggested solution , it now print like this 1-23-235%28K%29

Comment: And if you run this through `String result = URLDecoder.decode(cookie, "UTF-8");` on the Java side, you'll get your cookie back, intact...

Comment: I am writing this. copy paste.. String uom=URLDecoder.decode(getCookie[i].getValue(), "UTF-8");